# How to make an item in recycler support two layouts

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm making an app using android studio and I'm using recycler view to display items that are available in my stock but the probe is it displays items whose quantity have gone below 0 as well so I want to blur out those items so user can't have access to them. I have a different layout ready but how to I put it in this code

Code I'm currently using

```
void show(){

   FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Items> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Items>().setQuery(firebaseDatabase.child("Items").child(categ), Items.class).build();


   FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Items, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Items, NewOrder.UsersViewHolder>(options)
   {

       @Override
       public NewOrder.UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


           View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items,parent,false);

           return new NewOrder.UsersViewHolder(view);

       }

       @Override
       protected void onBindViewHolder(NewOrder.UsersViewHolder holder, int position, Items model) {

           holder.setName(model.getName());
           holder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
           holder.setProfilePic(model.getImage());
           holder.setPrice(model.getPrice());


           final String PID = getRef(position).getKey();

           String quant = model.getQuantity().toString();
           Integer qtt = Integer.parseInt(quant);
           if(qtt == 0){

               holder.mview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       Toast.makeText(NewOrder.this, "Sorry This Product is out of stock!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   }
               });

           }else {

               holder.mview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       Intent profileIntent = new Intent(NewOrder.this, Item.class);
                       profileIntent.putExtra("Product id", PID);
                       profileIntent.putExtra("Category", categ);
                       startActivity(profileIntent);

                   }
               });
           }
       }

   };

   items.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
   firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();


   }

public class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mview;


    public UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mview = itemView;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {

        TextView userNameView = mview.findViewById(R.id.name);
        String str = name;

        String cap = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
        userNameView.setText(cap);

    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {

        TextView userStatusView = mview.findViewById(R.id.description);
        userStatusView.setText(description);

    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {

        TextView userStatusView = mview.findViewById(R.id.price);
        userStatusView.setText("₹"+price);

    }

    public void setProfilePic(String profilepic) {






        final CircleImageView image = mview.findViewById(R.id.userSingleImage);


        final StorageReference mImageRef =
                FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Profile_image/thumbs/" + profilepic + ".jpg");
        final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

        Glide.with(mview)
                .load(mImageRef)
                .into(image);



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating 2 views in the item view (the single item for recycler view). and give it id.

then you can access that view in your adapter and check the condition for each item. then you can decide which view to show.

let me know if you need more clarifications.